# Component type angular directive ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-template

In the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            .....
        </head>
        <body ng-app="app">
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-info-msg.html">
                <strong>{{o.msg}}</strong>
            </script>
            <div ng-controller="emp as o">
                <div my-info-msg>

                </div>  
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

function MyController(){
    this.msg= 'This is a message';
}
app.controller('emp', MyController);


function MsgDirective(){
    return{
        template1Url: "my-info-msg.html"
    };
}
app.directive('myInfoMsg', MsgDirective);
```

---

custom directive `my-info-msg` does not add the template `<strong>{{o.msg}}</strong>` in `<div my-info-msg> </div>`.

Please help me!!!

Comment: Because you have template1Url, instead of templateUrl, there's a typo. Also I don't know why you use the directive the way you use it, using a script tag. Instead use it for example like: `<div my-info-msg></div>`

Comment: @emil.c My daughter has done this. Not me :) I did not get your second point. Because, I used `<div my-info-msg></div>`

Comment: My second point is irrelevant, I misunderstood the syntax as I usually use template in a separate html fine not using script tag so please ignore the second point. Does it work without the typo?

Answer (score 2):

As @emil.c has pointed out. You have a typo in your code:

```
templateUrl: "my-info-msg.html"
```

It works fine when you remove the "1" from your `template1Url`.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Q20v7zSHHVPNJOOievrm?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in `template1Url`, remove the `1` between `template` and `Url` and you should be fine.